# Unable to Identify DevExpress GridControl using Ranorex test automation tool through C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, automated-tests, ranorex

In Visual Studio 2013, I'm writing Test Automated methods with C# code for a WPF application using Ranorex tool references: I could not able to identify the DevExpress GridControl located in WPF application and unable to retrieve its properties(Grid data (Rows and columns)).  Can someone please help.

```
var devExgrid = form.FindSingle<RanorexDataGrid>(".//element[@automationid='dg_UserOrders']");
```

**Error**:

```
The type 'Ranorex.Controls.RanorexDataGrid' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Ranorex.Adapter.FindSingle<T>(Ranorex.Core.RxPath)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Ranorex.Controls.RanorexDataGrid' to 'Ranorex.Adapter'.
```

Comment: I have tried to understand what is a RanorexDataGrid and could not find any info on this type in the documentation.  What I would suggest is use the Ranorex spy on a grid item, add it to a repository and look at the type of adapter Ranorex is using to represent it (in the generated code).

Answer (score 0):

Track the UI element using Ranorex Spy and drag/drop it to a user code file in Rx Studio. Doing so, you'll see how to access this specific element with Ranorex.